# Why does this C# function exist in Visual Studio 2015 but not Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Just someone can explain me why this work on Visual Studio 2015 but not on Visual Studio 2017 ?

```
public static TConvert DynamicPop<TObject, TConvert>(this IEnumerable<TObject> obj, Converter<TObject, TConvert> converter, long @default = 1)
    {
        if (obj.Count() == 0)
        {
            dynamic _defaut = @default;
            return (TConvert)_defaut;
        }
        var collection = obj.ConvertAll<TConvert>(converter);
        collection.Sort();
        dynamic lastValue = collection.Last();
        return (TConvert)(lastValue + 1);
    }
```

That said to me that `ConvertAll` doesn't exist.

Comment: `ConvertAll` is apparently a method on `List<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. Maybe you have an extension method in one environment that is not present in the other?

Comment: In the VS 2015 solution, right click on `ConvertAll` and select `Go To Definition`. What comes up?

Comment: Given you are checking `Count()` earlier (so you are getting double enumeration) you should consider changing `IEnumerable<TObject> obj` to `List<TObject> obj`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the method `ConvertAll` is defined on MSDN as a method of `List<t>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx).

I can't tell you why this is working in Visual Studio 2015, but there is an easy fix to the code you can implement to make it work in Visual Studio 2017. Just change the convert line to:

```
var collection = obj.ToList().ConvertAll<TConvert>(converter);
```

Note that you'll need to have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

`ConvertAll` is not an available method on `IEnumerable<T>`. *In VS 2015 you must have been calling it via an extension method you built yourself (or which was referenced).*

One option might be to replace:

```
var collection = obj.ConvertAll<TConvert>(converter);
collection.Sort();
dynamic lastValue = collection.Last();
```

with:

```
dynamic lastValue = obj.Select(z => converter(z)).OrderByDescending(z => z).First();
```

Basically just replacing `ConvertAll` with `Select` which does roughly the same thing. The `OrderByDescending` replaces the `Sort` also.